# How to only include the maximum value per each ID in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

| JOB_ID | DAY_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 430 | 120 |
| 430 | 720 |
| 530 | 120 |
| 530 | 620 |
| 630 | 120 |
| 630 | 120 |
| 630 | 620 |
| 630 | 620 |

Should become:

| JOB_ID | DAY_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 430 | 720 |
| 530 | 620 |
| 630 | 620 |
| 630 | 620 |

Where only the rows where day_id is the maximum value is kept.

I'm using Oracle SQL developer.

Comment: Please search for existing questions using the tag [tag:greatest-n-per-group]

Comment: Can you share your coding attempt at this problem? @cjbbltr

Comment: max function and group by should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can work:

```
SELECT job_id, day_id
  FROM some_table tbl
 WHERE (job_id, day_id) IN (SELECT job_id, MAX(day_id)
                              FROM some_table
                             GROUP BY job_id);
```

Comment: This is what I wanted to show (but missed to check the job_id). To avoid duplicate answers, I deleted mine and gave you an upvote.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words! I am usually the one facepalming myself so it made me feel appeciated.

Answer (score 2):

You probably already figured out how to get the maximum value per JOB_ID like this:

```
WITH BASIC_AGGS AS (
SELECT
    JOB_ID,
    MAX(DAY_ID) as DAY_ID_MAX
FROM mytable
GROUP BY JOB_ID)

SELECT BASIC_AGGS.JOB_ID, BASIC_AGGS.DAY_ID_MAX
FROM BASIC_AGGS
```

But it sounds like you want to join this back to your original table in order to keep all the records where the maximum amount matches the row. Like this:

```
WITH BASIC_AGGS AS (
SELECT
    JOB_ID,
    MAX(DAY_ID) as DAY_ID_MAX
FROM mytable
GROUP BY JOB_ID)

SELECT BASIC_AGGS.JOB_ID, BASIC_AGGS.DAY_ID_MAX
FROM BASIC_AGGS
INNER JOIN mytable
ON BASIC_AGGS.JOB_ID = mytable.JOB_ID
AND BASIC_AGGS.JOB_ID_MAX = mytable.DAY_ID
```

I'm not familiar with Oracle, but if it doesn't support using this style of SQL called CTE, you can write it in a different style that nests the first query as a subquery like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
INNER JOIN (SELECT JOB_ID, MAX(DAY_ID) as DAY_ID_MAX 
    FROM mytable 
    GROUP BY JOB_ID
   ) as rsMAX
ON mytable.JOB_ID = rsMAX.JOB_ID
AND mytable.DAY_ID = rsMAX.DAY_ID_MAX
```

Comment: The second query (with the CTE) is good.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT X.JOB_ID,X.DAY_ID   FROM
(
  SELECT C.JOB_ID,C.DAY_ID,
   RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY C.JOB_ID ORDER BY C.DAY_ID DESC)XCOL
   FROM TABLE_DATA AS C
)X WHERE X.XCOL=1
ORDER BY X.JOB_ID
```

Comment: The output of this query doesn't match the required output.

Comment: Still wrong output for JOB_ID `630`.

Comment: based on the given test data can not see it

Comment: @Sergey In the expected output, row `630` should show up twice. Your query will show it only once.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=be4503902380a5ecaa760e9bf03a8c98